# python, how do I parallelize several calls to the same function without lose execution time

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have some trouble to parallelize a function.
I would like use a function several time in parallel way:

```
def f_diff_coord(vect1,vect2):
    return vect1-vect2
```

This function need to be computed several time with different vectors in a general for loop.
So my code is writing in that way:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool


def f_diff_coord(vect1,vect2):
    return vect1-vect2,vect1+vect2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(3)
    for _ in manytime
        vect_a = np.arange(10)+2
        vect_b = np.arange(10)
        vect_c = np.arange(10)
        vect_d = np.arange(10)+3
        #vect_ are juste for example
        r1=p.apply_async(f_diff_coord, (vect_a,vect_b,) )
        r2=p.apply_async(f_diff_coord, (vect_c,vect_d,) )
        data_a = r1.get()
        data_b = r2.get()
        #do somthing with data_
```

I run this kind of code with 3 pools and it seems being parallelized (in my  Task Manager on windows). However, the computation time is quite longer than in the serialized code. Am I missing something or is it the fact that the call to several processes takes a lot of time to be initiated?

Comment: I don't see any need for multithreading in your problem, maybe you just need to use dictionaries and lists.

Comment: The f_diff_coor function is just a reduced example. I perform long computation inside this function. However, the principle of the function remain: a funtion which receive 2 vectors and return one vector.

Answer (score 0):

use the [multiprocessing](https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/basics.html) module to parallelise your calls

Comment: I tried this module. However I wasn't able to succeed using this modul with input and output paramters for the called function.

Comment: there are various ways of handling the return values - you should read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) about Queues or shared objects - I would suggest attempting to solve your proplem using the multiprocessing module and when you run into problems post a new question showing your code

Comment: I modified the question to be more precise on my issue